# How to set event handler as passive in Dash plotly to avoid data points being skipped

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

I am using dash plotly with python to plot line graphs I am using the extendData property of the graph to update the traces to avoid redrawing the graph. I am facing a problem where the graphs skip few data points. I am also getting some console warnings which are as follows

```
async-plotlyjs.v1_16_0m1617903285.js:2 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
```

```
async-plotlyjs.v1_16_0m1617903285.js:2 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'wheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952
```

I think the reason for data points being skipped is this waring as it may block the callback from being called. More data points are being skipped when I move from the graph tab to the other tab(let's say I move from the graph tab to the StackOverflow tab). How do I prevent this from happening? or if there is another way to do this please feel free to post it in the comments.

these are the screenshots where it shipped one data point.

[image: data point 99]

[image: skipped data point 100]

[image: data point 101]

FYI I am using
Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.107 (Official Build) (64-bit)
but the problem is persistent on other browsers as well.

Below mentioned is the code

```
import random
import webbrowser
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import numpy as np
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph-voltage',
                figure={
                    'layout': {
                        'title': 'Voltage',
                        'xaxis': {
                            'title': 'Time'
                        },
                        'yaxis': {
                            'title': 'Voltage in V',
                            'range': [0, 5],
                        }
                    },
                    'data': [{'name': 'Cell 01', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 02', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 03', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 04', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 05', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 06', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 07', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 08', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 09', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 10', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 11', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 12', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 13', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 14', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 15', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             {'name': 'Cell 16', 'type': 'line', 'x': [], 'y': []},
                             ]
                }
            ),
        ], ),
    ]),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-graph-update',
        interval=0.5 * 1000,
        n_intervals=0),
])


@app.callback(Output('graph-voltage', 'extendData'),
              [Input('interval-graph-update', 'n_intervals')]
              )
def extend_single_trace(n_intervals):
    CVT_CELL1 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL2 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL3 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL4 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL5 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL6 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL7 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL8 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL9 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL10 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL11 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL12 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL13 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL14 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL15 = np.array([])
    CVT_CELL16 = np.array([])
    CVT_TIME_STAMP = np.array([])

    CVT_CELL1 = np.append(CVT_CELL1, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL2 = np.append(CVT_CELL2, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL3 = np.append(CVT_CELL3, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL4 = np.append(CVT_CELL4, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL5 = np.append(CVT_CELL5, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL6 = np.append(CVT_CELL6, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL7 = np.append(CVT_CELL7, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL8 = np.append(CVT_CELL8, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL9 = np.append(CVT_CELL9, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL10 = np.append(CVT_CELL10, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL11 = np.append(CVT_CELL11, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL12 = np.append(CVT_CELL12, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL13 = np.append(CVT_CELL13, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL14 = np.append(CVT_CELL14, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL15 = np.append(CVT_CELL15, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_CELL16 = np.append(CVT_CELL16, random.randint(0,5))
    CVT_TIME_STAMP = np.append(CVT_TIME_STAMP, n_intervals)

    return (dict(x=[CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP,
                    CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP,
                    CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, CVT_TIME_STAMP, ],
                 y=[CVT_CELL1, CVT_CELL2, CVT_CELL3, CVT_CELL4, CVT_CELL5, CVT_CELL6, CVT_CELL7, CVT_CELL8, CVT_CELL9,
                    CVT_CELL10, CVT_CELL11, CVT_CELL12, CVT_CELL13, CVT_CELL14, CVT_CELL15, CVT_CELL16],
                 )
            )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:5050/')
    app.run_server(port=5050, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason Dash graph skips the data points is that it cannot handle large amounts of data in the specified update rate of the page. The workaround for this is to either reduce the amount of data or increase the update rate.
I hope this is helpful.